# Why are iPhone 12 Pro stereo video frames vertically displaced?

Tags: ios, camera, computer-vision, avfoundation

*UPDATE: The issue seems to be down to not correcting for the cameras' intrinsic matrices, but those matrices are not available. See EDIT 3 below.*

I'm capturing video using [`AVCaptureMultiCamSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturemulticamsession), [`builtInDualCamera`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/devicetype/2727142-builtindualcamera), two outputs, and an [`AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedataoutputsynchronizer), for use in computer vision. I'm cropping the wide-angle camera image so the fields of view match. The video is captured in the cameras' natural orientation, i.e. "home button" to the right.

Since the wide-angle and telephoto devices are only physically displaced along the horizontal camera axis, on the iPhone 12 Pro at least, I'm expecting depth disparity only along the horizontal image axis. This mostly holds up, except for one weird issue:

If and only if I hold the device roughly upright in landscape orientation, there is a slight *vertical* disparity between the images, corresponding to roughly 11 pixels in the wide-angle frame at 1920x1080. However, if I hold the device upright in portrait orientation, or hold it flat (parallel to the ground), the image-space vertical disparity vanishes. It's a gradual transition, so the closer I am to upright and landscape, the more of the image-space vertical disparity I get.

Since the problem is definitely dependent on the physical device orientation, <strike>it seems like the gyro has to be involved somehow</strike>. EDIT: It could also be either the accelerometer or [OIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stabilization). Is there any AVFoundation setting that would make it utilise the gyro, accelerometer or OIS during video capture? The only one I can think of is video stabilisation, but that's definitely turned off.

Below are some screenshots illustrating the issue. The screenshots are all in the cameras' natural orientation, i.e. "home button" to the right. They are cropped. The blue circle is from the wide-angle lens, the red is from the telephoto lens.

EDIT: The first picture is taken with the device upright and the "home button" on the right. With the "home button" to the *left*, the vertical disparity is the same from the user's point of view, i.e. it's inverted relative to the video frames.

EDIT 2: The input ports are acquired by calling `ports(for:sourceDeviceType:sourceDevicePosition:)` for device types `builtInWideAngleCamera` and `builtInTelephotoCamera`. The virtual device `builtInDualCamera` also has a different port for composite input, where it grabs frames from either of the cameras, depending on the current zoom level. Weirdly, the latter port seems to produce identical frames to the `builtInWideAngleCamera` port. In other words, the `builtInWideAngleCamera` port outputs frames from either of the two physical devices, depending on the zoom level. This seems like a bug.

**EDIT 3: From 36:28, [this WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/225/) strongly implies you need to correct for the constituent devices' intrinsic matrices in order to relate the images to each other. This is probably the issue. Unfortunately, `isCameraIntrinsicMatrixDeliverySupported` returns `false` for both of my connections, even though my capture session is set up exactly as described in the talk.**

Upright landscape:
[image: Upright landscape]

Flat:
[image: Flat]

Upright portrait:
[image: Upright portrait]

Comment: Did you check the [extrinsic matrix](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/3229937-extrinsicmatrix) between the cameras and whether it changes when rotating the device?

Comment: Good question @FrankSchlegel. The extrinsic matrix does not change as I move the camera. It is: `simd_float4x3([[0.9999969, -0.0001923358, -0.0024844604], [0.0001978918, 0.9999975, 0.0022362475], [0.002484024, -0.0022367323, 0.9999944], [-15.419649, 0.0027622615, 0.12930928]])`, i.e. virtually no rotation, and virtually only horizontal translation.

Comment: Have you seen the note about video stabilization in the documentation? Maybe that's affecting the alignment.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Video stabilisation is off by default, and I've also verified that it's off. Which note in the documentation are you referring to?

Comment: From [extrinsicMatrix(from:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/3229937-extrinsicmatrix), the "Important" section at the bottom.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel ah, gotcha. I never had video stabilisation enabled in my testing, so that shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in [this WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/225/), you have to correct for the intrinsic matrices to relate video frames from the respective cameras to each other.

Oddly, it seems that `AVCaptureConnection`'s `isCameraIntrinsicMatrixDeliverySupported` returns `false` unless <strike>both connections have</strike> the connection has been added to the session, in which case it returns `true` <strike>(given the session topology in question)</strike>.

The intrinsic matrices of the respective cameras do change in real time, which accounts for the unexpected vertical disparity.

[This WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/) describes the intrinsic matrix in a bit more detail.